# Join on two columns from seperate files

Tags: bash, shell, join, multiple-columns

I have two files:

File1:

```
   chr1 100736194  46   0.731   +   100735713   100736636
   chr1 100736194  49   0.879   +   100735723   100736646
   chr1 100736196  54   0.952   +   100735753   100736666
```

File2:

```
   chr1 100735713  100736636  +  BMCHAS
   chr1 100735723  100736646  +  ATCGSG
   chr1 100735753  100736666  +  BDUSUS
```

I want to join file 1 and 2 based on

- file1's column 6 and 7, and
- file2's column 2 and 3

to output something like:

```
   chr1 100736194  46   0.731   +   100735713   100736636  BMCHAS
   chr1 100736194  49   0.879   +   100735723   100736646  ATCGSG
   chr1 100736196  54   0.952   +   100735753   100736666  BDUSUS
```

I don't know how to use join for more than a single column and I looked up an awk solution and have been trying to implement that but I think I am not right somewhere, the command that I am using is: awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$5;next}{$3=a[$7,$8];print}' OFS='\t' file2 file1,

Also, it is important to match not one, but two columns from each file, because the single columns are not unique enough. This means I cannot use single-column matching solutions such as only matching file1's column 6 with file2's column 2 only, it must use the multiple specified columns above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would probably get more answers if you tagged bash or shell or something

Comment: Would it be ok just to join on one field such as file1's 6th column matching file2's 2nd column?

Comment: I think I would rather use both since the individual columns are not unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `join`. The trick is to attach the two columns together so they get treated as one.

I've done it here with `sed` but you could use `awk` or whatever you like.

The `<(..)` syntax is **bash-specific** and means approximately "create a temporary named pipe and pass that as a file".

```
join \
   -1 6  \
   -2 2  \
   -o "1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 0 2.4"  \
   <(sed 's/\([0-9]\{9\}\) *\([0-9]\{9\}\)/\1-\2/' file1) \
   <(sed 's/\([0-9]\{9\}\) *\([0-9]\{9\}\)/\1-\2/' file2) \
 | sed 's/-/  /'
```

This works with GNU sed (I have 4.2.2); you may need to make adjustments for other sed implementations.

The input `sed` commands convert your input files to look like this:

```
chr1 100736194  46   0.731   +   100735713-100736636
```

The output `sed` command undoes the change.

The output format (`-o "1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 0 2.4"`) gives the output you asked for:

```
chr1 100736194 46 0.731 + 100735713  100736636 BMCHAS
chr1 100736194 49 0.879 + 100735723  100736646 ATCGSG
chr1 100736196 54 0.952 + 100735753  100736666 BDUSUS
```

Answer (score 0):

by awk

```
 awk ' NR==FNR{ a[$2 FS $3]=$5;next} ($6 FS $7) in a { print $0 FS a[$6 FS $7]} ' file2 file1
```